# My outside a/c unit will not kick on

Tags: air-conditioning

Earlier today the a/c unit tripped the breaker.  I reset the breaker but the outside unit will not kick on. Please advise.

Comment: How do I test the capacitor for my outside a/c unit

Comment: Could be you need a new capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Some component has failed in the a/c unit. This act of failing caused the breaker to trip. Now the failed component is preventing the a/c unit form starting.

The unit needs checking to find out which component has failed so it can be replaced. Disconnect the supply and use a multimeter to trace the control path.

Comment: This is highly likely, but not guaranteed.  Modern compressors often have an internal breaker as well, not to mention a control panel with its own CPU that might require acknowledging an event before it'll reset.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to read your Owner's Manual and see if it has reset instructions.  If you have a new-ish unit, there may be error codes displayed on a control panel inside the compressor housing (or on the thermostat panel if there is a display there).

And it should go without saying, but: check to be sure no debris is jamming the fan, that there are no obvious signs of broken tubing, scorch marks from burnt components, etc.